# AddTransient won't draw image AutoCAD 2023 .net c#

Tags: autocad-plugin

I want to draw a transient line by a specific distance when I hover over another line, but when I use the method ctm.AddTransient(line, AcGi.TransientDrawingMode.Main, 128, ints), it is not drawing any transient line. In another code I am using the method with block references as ctm.AddTransient(bref, AcGi.TransientDrawingMode.DirectShortTerm, 128, ints) and it works without problems.

Now I am working on a code which I changed some parts from another source in order to understand how I can achieve my goal.

I have used both AcGi.TransientDrawingMode.Main and AcGi.TransientDrawingMode.DirectShortTerm modes, tried to change the transient line's coordinates to a fixed coordinate and added the method ctm.UpdateTransient(bref, ints) to the code in order to find a solution but none of them worked.

Here is the full code for you to examine. I am a newbie so please be more specific about your suggestions and I will try to understand them as much as I can. Thank you for your help.

```
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Geometry;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput;
using System;
using AcGi = Autodesk.AutoCAD.GraphicsInterface;

public class PointMonitorTooltips

{

    [CommandMethod("SM")]

    public static void StartMonitor()

    {

        Editor ed =

          Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor;

        ed.PointMonitor +=

          new PointMonitorEventHandler(ed_PointMonitor);

    }



    [CommandMethod("XM")]

    public static void StopMonitor()

    {

        Editor ed =

          Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor;

        ed.TurnForcedPickOn();

        ed.PointMonitor -=

          new PointMonitorEventHandler(ed_PointMonitor);

    }



    static void ed_PointMonitor(object sender, PointMonitorEventArgs e)
    {
        Editor ed = (Editor)sender;

        AcGi.TransientManager ctm = AcGi.TransientManager.CurrentTransientManager;

        IntegerCollection ints = new IntegerCollection(new int[] { });

        try
        {
            FullSubentityPath[] paths = e.Context.GetPickedEntities();

            // Open a transaction to create the transient line
            using (Transaction tr = ed.Document.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
            {
                foreach (FullSubentityPath path in paths)
                {
                    ObjectId[] ids = path.GetObjectIds();

                    if (ids.Length > 0)
                    {
                        ObjectId id = ids[ids.GetUpperBound(0)];

                        // Get the entity
                        Entity ent = (Entity)tr.GetObject(id, OpenMode.ForRead);
                        Type objtype = ent.GetType();

                        // Create a transient line based on the entity's position and orientation
                        if (objtype == typeof(Line))
                        {

                            Line linecoor = (Line)ent.Clone();

                            Point3d start = linecoor.StartPoint;
                            start = start.Add(new Vector3d(5.0, 5.0, 0.0));

                            Point3d end = linecoor.EndPoint;
                            end = end.Add(new Vector3d(5.0, 5.0, 0.0));

                            Line line = new Line(start, end);

                            // Add the transient line
                            ed.WriteMessage("\nAdding transient line..."); // This part constantly sending messages 

                            ctm.AddTransient(line, AcGi.TransientDrawingMode.Main, 128, ints); // This is the part that is not working
                        }
                    }
                }

                tr.Commit();
            }
        }

        catch
        {
            // Exception handling code here
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem myself. Take a look at these two test clasess:

```cs
public class TestCommand1
{
    private DBObjectCollection _markers = new DBObjectCollection();
    private IntegerCollection intColl = new IntegerCollection();

    [CommandMethod("TempMarker1")]
    public void TestTransient1()
    {
        try
        {
            var locationDrawing = new Point3d(0, 0, 0);
            var circleMarker = new Circle(locationDrawing, Vector3d.ZAxis, 5) { ColorIndex = 1 };
            TransientManager.CurrentTransientManager.AddTransient(circleMarker, TransientDrawingMode.DirectTopmost, 128, intColl);
            _markers.Add(circleMarker);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.ShowAlertDialog(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```cs
public class TestCommand2
{
    private DBObjectCollection _markers = new DBObjectCollection();
    private IntegerCollection intColl = new IntegerCollection();

    [CommandMethod("TempMarker2")]
    public void TestTransient2()
    {
        try
        {
            var locationDrawing = new Point3d(10, 10, 0);
            var circleMarker = new Circle(locationDrawing, Vector3d.ZAxis, 5) { ColorIndex = 1 };
            TransientManager.CurrentTransientManager.AddTransient(circleMarker, TransientDrawingMode.DirectTopmost, 128, intColl);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.ShowAlertDialog(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

You will notice that the only difference between the two examples is that the first one adds circle object into a collection and thus keeps a reference to the object created. In the second example circle is only added to TransientManager.

When you start these commands in AutoCAD you will see this:

- For the first example - circle object persists in the drawing after
  added.
- For the second example - object appears only for a second and    then
  it disappears.

So my guess is this is related to garbage collector mechanism.